# Failed to execute script by calling another script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have two shell scripts for two different user user 'a' and user 'root':

**a.sh** for user '**a**'

```
export CODE=`pwd | cut -d / -f 5`
isEnabled=`grep -i isEnabled $HOME/$CODE/config/code.properties | awk -F'=' '{print $2}'`
```

**b.sh** for user **'root'**

```
su - a -c "sh /export/home/a/a1/bin/a.sh status
```

As you can see, root execute script b.sh which execute script a.sh
but actually it failed since it does not find the path to the script since the
variable $CODE in a.sh probably missing in run time while running b.sh

after investigation i tired the following in **b.sh**:

```
. /path/to/a.sh
source /path/to/a.sh
. /path/to/a.sh "$CODE"
. $(/path/to/a.sh $CODE)
```

Can someone please advise?

Thank you all.

Comment: When `su - a` is done, current directory would be set to home directory of user `a`.  I think that would throw off your logic in `a.sh`.  Why do you need to depend on the current directory? Can the path to `code.properties` be derived in a better way?

Comment: when executing a.sh by a user it's working perfect. but when i executing it by root it throw an error regrading unknown path since $CODE is missing to root

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$CODE` should be there, but it will be set to a's home directory. Try using `basename $0` instead of `pwd`. That will get the directory the script is being executed from, rather than the current working directory of user executing it.

Comment: didn't sure i understand you. can you please give an example

Comment: @Asfbar Try changing this line in your code:

    `export CODE='pwd | cut -d / -f 5'`

To this:

    `'export CODE='basename $0 | cut -d / -f 5'`

(Just pretend the single quotes are backticks, I can't figure out how markdown is interpreted in comments). That will get the directory a.sh is in, instead of the user's home directory. If you use pwd, then your cut command will not return anything since the user's home directory probably doesn't have a path that long.

Comment: @Asfbar Also, it looks like you might want to use `cut -d / -f 4` instead of `cut -d / -f 5`. That will return the name of a subdirectory of a user's home directory.